# Facebook Messenger API not sending "messaging" webhook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-webhooks

Trying to setup a basic webhook to fire when a page received a message. If I manually curl a message, my server gets it. If I use app dashboard to test something like "message reactions", my server gets it. But any message to the page, sends NOTHING to my server. No request at all of any type.

I seem to have followed all the steps. Everything in the dashboard is green checkmarks. I've tried setting everything up from scratch using the dashboard and from scratch using the API.

[image: Messenger API Settings]

## **Callback URL**

Seems to be setup properly. In my logs I see the FB request coming in with the correct token. API response is good and the Dashboard seems to show that everything is correct.

**App Review & Status**
App is LIVE and approved for Advanced "messaging" permission.

## **API Flow**

**1. POST request to /subscriptions**
Response is `{"success":true}`. I verify this by making a GET request to /subscriptions and get back this:

```
{"data":[{"object":"page","callback_url":"REDACTED (url starts with https:\/\/)","active":true,"fields":[{"name":"messaging_postbacks","version":"v19.0"},{"name":"messages","version":"v19.0"},{"name":"message_deliveries","version":"v19.0"},{"name":"message_echoes","version":"v19.0"},{"name":"message_reactions","version":"v19.0"},{"name":"message_reads","version":"v19.0"}]}]}
```

**2. POST request to /subscribed_apps**
Response is `{"success":true}`. Verify this with a GET request to /subscribed_apps. Response:

```
{"data":[{"link":"REDACTED","name":"Website Chat","id":"REDACTED(matched my appID)","subscribed_fields":["messages","messaging_postbacks"]}]}
```

I've tried subscribing/unsubscribing to almost every "messaging" related webhook so that's why right now the `fields` aren't matching. But it doesn't matter what I subscribe to or unsubscribe from, nothing is every triggered when a new message comes to the page.

I've tested with multiple FB users. Mostly testing with my own which is an admin on the page but doesn't work with other users anyways.

### **Dashboard Message Test doesn't work**

In the app dashboard > Webhooks I CANNOT test the "messages" hook. When I click "test" the webhooks element goes "blank"? I go from this: [image: 1]
To this: [image: I hate this]

I've tried Chrome, Safari, & Firefox. Fresh install on Firefox with no adblockers or any extensions. Wifi on/off. VPN on/off. Nothing I can do for this to work and there's never an error.

### **Dashboard Testing other Message hooks WORKS**

For example, clicking "Test" on "Message Reactions" successfully shows up on my server. So the webhook url should be good and my server implementation should be good. I'm logging the request as soon as it comes in, regardless of the type so I'll catch anything FB throws at me.

### **Manually curl test works...**

Sending this works perfectly: `curl -k -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":43674671559,"time":1460620433256,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":123456789},"recipient":{"id":987654321},"timestamp":1460620433123,"message":{"mid":"mid.1460620432888:f8e3412003d2d1cd93","seq":12604,"text":"Testing Chat Bot .."}}]}]}' https://REDACTED/api/webhook`

My server receives it and handles it just like it should.

### **No errors**

No webhook errors in my server console. No webhook errors in Dashboard Messenger API Settings > Show Recent Errors.

### **FB Support is ???**

I don't know if I'm just missing brain cells at this point but there is no FB support like live chat or a ticketing system. Any "help" menu I've been to just ends up linking me to the docs. Trying to create a "Bug" ticket tells me I can't: [image: I feel very supported]

#### **I've reached the end of my sanity. I don't know. ChatGPT doesn't know. I don't think FB(meta?) knows. If StackOverflow doesn't know then nobody knows.**